# How can I add leading zeros to dates in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to add leading zeros to a number if it is less than two digits and combine two such numbers into single one without space between them.

**My Attempt:**

```
select ( extract (year from t.Dt)
         || to_char(extract (month from t.Dt),'09')
         || to_char(extract (day from t.Dt),'09') ) as dayid 
  from ATM_FACTS t;
```

**Result:**

[image]

So, my problem is how can I remove the space in between month-year and month-day. I used

```
select ( extract (year from t.Dt)
         || to_number(to_char(extract (month from t.Dt),'09'))
         || to_number(to_char(extract (day from t.Dt),'09')) ) as dayid 
  from ATM_FACTS t;
```

but the leading zeros disappear.

Comment: i didn't really understand if you want or the zero's or not, but is you don't then maybe something like `select to_number(replace(to_char(t.Dt,'DS'),'/','')) from dual`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't look like you want to add leading zero's, it looks like you're not converting your date to a character in exactly the way you want. The [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) of TO_CHAR() is extremely powerful, make full use of it.

```
select to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') as dayid
  from atm_facts
```

To actually answer your question you can use a [number format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) with TO_CHAR() to pad with leading 's.

For instance, the following returns `006`

```
select to_char(6, 'fm009') from dual;
```

You can use the format model modifier `fm`, mentioned in the docs above, to remove leading spaces if necessary.

Comment: @Zane - it's polite to accept answers that helped solve your problem.

Comment: I would recommend reading the linked documentation @zane, the datetime format model for the 24 hour clock is `hh24` and for a minute is `mi`, so `to_char(dt, 'hh24mi')`

Comment: @BobJarvis, Thanks for your comment...I was about to do that

Comment: to_char is not a solution, since it adds a leading space. A solution is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814518/oracle-adding-leading-zeros-to-string-not-number

Comment: Not any more it doesn't @Wouter and the question may be asking about dates but it's still completely relevant to numbers and has been answered for numbers...

Answer (score 2):

Is t.Dt a DATE? You can format them in one single `to_char` statement:

```
to_char(t.Dt, 'YYYYMMDD')
```